# Using lxml XSLT output

Tags: python-3.x, xslt, lxml

I use Python and lxml.
I am trying to append the result of an XML transformation to another XML object which results in an incorrect type error.

I have two xml files that I want to combine in the same XML tree, but first I need to apply an XSLT transform to one of the two files.
If I convert the result of the XSLT to a string and then parse it back, it works but I'd rather skip this step and directly use the XSLT output.

```
#Code that works:
xsl = etree.XSLT(etree.parse('Stylesheet.xsl'));
xml = etree.fromstring('<ROOT/>');
xml.append(etree.parse('FileA.xml')));
xml.append(etree.fromstring(str(xsl(etree.parse('FileB.xml')))));
```

```
#Code that results in an error:
xsl = etree.XSLT(etree.parse('Stylesheet.xsl'));
xml = etree.fromstring('<ROOT/>');
xml.append(etree.parse('FileA.xml')));
xml.append(xsl(etree.parse('FileB.xml')));
```

The error message follows:

```
TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got lxml.etree._XSLTResultTree)
```

Comment: Does `xml.append(xsl(etree.parse('FileB.xml')).getroot());` instead of `xml.append(xsl(etree.parse('FileB.xml')));` work?

Comment: Yes, that seems working as expected. Can You submit this as a solution so I can give You credit for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  API documentation suggests that

```
 xml.append(xsl(etree.parse('FileB.xml')).getroot());
```

should work, I.e. instead of trying to append the whole result tree you can simply append  its root elements.